# how to convert decimal to binary with 0 in python

Tags: python, string, binary, integer, decimal

so i want to convert all list decimal to binary contain with 0.
but what i make its have int type and the all the 0 is gone.

> input = [6, 7, 2, 11, 14, 15, 10, 3, 6, 7, 2, 11, 14, 15, 10, 3]

> output = [110, 111, 10, 1011, 1110, 1111, 1010, 11, 110, 111, 10,
> 1011, 1110, 1111, 1010, 11]

can someone fix my code so it have 0 in the front? **like 00000110 its mean 6**

here's my code:

```
def dec_to_bin(x):
    print(x)
    for a in range(0, len(x)):
        keluar = x[a]
        biner = int(bin(keluar)[2:])
        x[a] = biner
    return x
```

Comment: Don't use `range(0, len(x)` this is an anti-pattern. Use `for idx, a in enumerate(x)`

Answer (score 0):

You need the `str` type to retain zeros.  You can use a [format string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec) to instruct the number to display as 8-digit-with-leading-zero binary:

```py
def dec_to_bin(x):
    return [f'{a:08b}' for a in x]

result = dec_to_bin([6, 7, 2, 11])
print(result)
print(' '.join(result))
```

Output:

```
['00000110', '00000111', '00000010', '00001011']
00000110 00000111 00000010 00001011
```

Answer (score 0):

`zfill` function will fill leading zero on the left. You can specify the digit on the parameter:

```
x[a] = biner.zfill(8)
```